# Finding a list of companies on the market

Tags: united-states, stocks

I'm trying to analyze the 10-K/20-F report by comparing the revenue and growth rate with other companies.

I've tried to use the [S&P 500 list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies), but it only contains the best companies. How can I find a more comprehensive list  of companies in an industry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search for 1 example of the company (e.g. AAPL) on [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html).
2. Note down the Standard Industry Classification (SIC), e.g. 3571 for AAPL

[image: two]

3. Search the SIC on EDGAR:

[image: three]

4. View Result

[image: four]

Answer (score 0):

FINVIZ offers about 15 free screeners which include over 7,500 stocks.

The one titled OVERVIEW lists the Sector and Industry for nearly 8,300 stocks.  The only catch is that you have to have a clever way to capture 415 pages of data (20 per page).  Here's part of the first page:

[image]

Comment: Yes, stock screeners are useful. To understand the terms used, 'Sector' is an industry group and 'Industry' is a narrower group. https://finviz.com/screener.ashx  Just select the one you are interested in from the dropdown menus and then sort by Market Cap descending.